# Passenger to the Caribbean from Spain

Tags: manifest, spain, mexico, puerto-rico

I’ve been looking for ship passenger manifests from Spain to the Caribbean, Puerto Rico, and Mexico. I’ve never been able to find anything originating from Spain. Has anyone had any luck with this. I belong to Ancestry and Family Search. I’ve also tried the National Archives.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy.SE, A. Cwik.  It would be helpful if you said which countries in the Caribbean you meant (aside from the US territory of Puerto Rico).  When you say the National Archives, do you mean in Spain?  Large numbers of manifests from Europe to the United States have survived, most or maybe even all from the 20th century and many before that.  We also have some from other countries to the US and also German outgoing records to the US.  Beyond that, it's hit or miss.  But generally they are held in the destination country, or in the country the ship was registered in.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Sorry for confusion. The countries I need to research are Spain, Mexico, Puerto Rico, Canary Islands, Cuba , Dominican Republic.

Comment: -Yes I have search United States national archives, they gave me a link for national archives in Spain. I tried that link, but they have nothing online for my search. You have to go into their location.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ibero-american Migratory Movements](http://pares.mcu.es/MovimientosMigratorios/staticContent.form?viewName=presentacion) portal includes personal details of emigrants from Spain to Mexico, Cuba, Puerto Rico, Dominican Republic, Uruguay and Argentina. Using the [search form](http://pares.mcu.es/MovimientosMigratorios/buscadorAvanzadoFilter.form), you can access to digitised records, documents and images.